# Text to Columns issue in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that when run in one workbook will open up another workbook in the  background, change column F of this newly opened workbook from text to date, save changes and then close the workbook that was just opened. In the code I am trying I keep getting the error message 'Run-time error '1004': TextToColumns method of Range class failed'. Do you know what is wrong and how I can fix it?

```
Sub Test()

Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet

xlApp.Visible = False

Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("directory_file_to_open")

Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("worksheet_of_data")
xlWS.Unprotect

    xlWS.Columns("F:F").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Set xlWS = Nothing
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlWB.Close True
Set xlWB = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully qualify the `Destination:=Range("F1")`. If not it will be `Range("F1")` in `ActiveSheet`. This is probably wrong since it should be `Range("F1")` in `xlWS`.

So

```
xlWS.Columns("F:F").TextToColumns Destination:=xlWS.Range("F1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```